# CouchDB - cannot configure correctly admin user after installation

Tags: ubuntu, login, administrator, couchdb

I attempted to install a few times CouchDB on my Ubuntu (18.04), following the official [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/install/unix.html).

When running `sudo apt install -y couchdb` I get the guided installation in the terminal and when prompted to add and confirm a password for the 'admin' user I follow the instructions.
Installation seems to be completed without any error message and I know that CouchDB is running because if I type `curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/` I get the expected welcome response.

But if I try to perform any other operation (e.g. `url -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/new_db`) I get the following error: `{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not a server admin."}`.

Guessing ti could have been a problem with curl I also tried the GUI on http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/#login, but when trying to login with 'admin' and the password I set I am told my credentials are wrong.
I cannot create another admin user either as I need to be logged as admin to do that.

Any suggestion on how to get out of this impasse?
Is it possible that, as I dis-installed and reinstalled, older credentials still exist somewhere creating a conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

**Differently from what said in the official CouchDb documentation**, when running the guided setup in the terminal you are 'creating an admin user and CouchDb expects authentication thereafter for everything but the simplest GET requests.
Therefore you need to pass your credentials to CouchDB.
Here are some ways to do that, using curl or Python.

Creating a new database

`$ curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/new_db -u 'admin:password'`

Same operation split in two lines (useful if you want to write more than one command, so you can save retyping credentials)

`$ HOST="http://admin:password@127.0.0.1:5984"`

`$ curl -X PUT $HOST/new_db`

Same in a Python (3.6) script

```
import json, requests
answer = requests.put('http://127.0.0.1:5984/new_db', auth=('admin', 'password'))
print(answer.json())
```